# Filter field by length with OData

Tags: odata

I'm in the strange situation that I have some numbers stored as text in a DB. Not being very familiar with OData, I'm trying to write a query that handles those strings as actual numbers.

```
$filter=(((length(Document/DocumentSet/ReferenceNumbers) ge 3) and (Document/DocumentSet/ReferenceNumbers gt '100')))
```

is the best I could come up with, but that gives me an ODataException

```
The argument for an invocation of a function with name 'length' is not a single value. All arguments for this function must be single values.
```

Or if I try to use (I'm still trying to figure out which one is right, I really don't know OData):

```
$filter=(((length(Document/DocumentSet/ReferenceNumbers/Number) ge 3) and (Document/DocumentSet/ReferenceNumbers/Number gt '100')))
```

then

```
The parent value for a property access of a property 'Number' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.
```

The question is: is there any way to filter something with OData by length?

Comment: Can you add some information: what is the set you are filtering on (part before `$filter`)? What is the data model (from `$metadata` endpoint) for this set elements? I guess that `ReferenceNumbers` is an array, so you have to use lambda for filtering. So far I cannot help more, but `length` and `gt` may be enough with lambda. Full list of operations (there is also casting available): http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358

Comment: The part before `$filter` is not a set, I believe. (The original implementation is non-REST thing sold as a REST thing) The `$metadata` part of the question I don't even understand (sorry). Anyway, I'll try the lambdas, I've seen a few around in the code, probably they're there for a reason.

Comment: In OData there is an endpoint `root/$metadata` which returns a service description, Entity Data Model. And `$filter` should run on a collection to be filtered (this is what I've meant this by "set"). Let me know if I can help you.

Comment: @Mate: I still couldn't get the $metadata out from the system, but your first comment is the solution for me: I need the lambdas. Would you turn that into an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you posted, I understood that `ReferenceNumbers` property is an array, because errors tell about *not a single value*.

For filtering on arrays, you need to use lambda operators ([5.1.1.10 in the official OData documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358)):

- `any` - when at least one entry has to match the conditions
- `all` - when all the array entries have to match them

And then `length` with `gt` should work for you. Example request - all the `ReferenceNumbers` should be greater than 100:

`root/set?$filter=Document/DocumentSet/ReferenceNumbers/any(refNum:refNum gt '100')`